# AppDelegate declaration in a second view

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, appdelegate

I have an issue with my App and maybe the way off managing AppDelegate. 
I have 2 views one is the main view and the second is for the setting. 
My first view will access to my core data (7 IP Address in string). When going to the second view, I'd like to modify IP Address into my CoreData. 
I have of course access to my data in my first view and I'm sending (segue) to my second view. 
My question is, I'd like to change my IP Address from my second view and save it into my core data. 
I know how to save, .... but, I need to create a ManagedObject, but, for that I need a AppDelegate. 
But, it seems that my AppDelegate declaration doesn't works. I mean, Xcode is telling me that AppDelegate is undeclared.

Can I segue my AppDelegate from 1st View to the Second ? 
Or
How to create an AppDelegate into my SecondView ?

thanks in advance for your help and support.

Comment: The context shouldn't be owned by the app delegate anyway (research why), but pass the context between view controllers anyway, don't go direct to the app delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Wain recommended, the best practice is to have the main view controller pass the managed object context to the settings view controller.

This is called dependency injection, and here's how you'd do it via a segue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showSettings" {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? SettingsViewController{
            // Pass our managed object context to the settings controller
            destinationVC.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext
        }
    }
}
```

You would add a `managedObjectContext` property to your Settings view controller, like so:

```
import CoreData

class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {

    var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext?
```

The benefit of dependency injection is that each view controller simply uses the context it was given, instead of looking to a "known" place (such as the `AppDelegate`) for a global managed object context.

This removes the tight coupling between view controllers and the `AppDelegate`, and also gives you the flexibility to use more than one `NSManagedObjectContext` throughout your app, which often becomes important as projects grow in size and complexity.

Apple recommends this practice in their [Accessing the Core Data Stack](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/stack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008283-SW2) documentation:

> When you create a view controller, you pass it the context it should
>   use. You pass an existing context, or (in a situation where you want
>   the new controller to manage a discrete set of edits) a new context
>   that you create for it. It’s typically the responsibility of the
>   application delegate to create a context to pass to the first view
>   controller that’s displayed.
>
> A view controller typically shouldn’t retrieve the context from a
>   global object such as the application delegate—this makes the
>   application architecture rigid.

**Update:**

In answer your comment about how to create an NSManagedObject, you only need an `NSManagedObjectContext`, which your second view controller now has.

```
let employee = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Employee", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Employee
```

See [Creating and Saving Managed Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/CreatingObjects.html) in Apple's *Core Data Programming Guide* for more details.

None of your view controllers should need to access the `AppDelegate` at all, since you're now passing around a context for them to use.

Comment: Thank you, got one more question. I succeeded to segue ManagedObjectContext, but, in my second view, for my value update into my entity, how can I create the ManagedContext without AppDelegate ?

Comment: You don't need the AppDelegate.  If you're following a tutorial that uses the AppDelegate to access the context or create managed objects, you should find a different tutorial :) I've updated the answer with an example and link.

Comment: Thank you, in your example you're using Employee when I'm using Adresses. Honestly I'm bit lost as, it seems not accessible. Do I need to create this class in my second view ?     class Adresses: NSManagedObject

Comment: Thanks PetahChristian, sorry, for that.

Comment: @fred No problem.  Posting code makes a big difference.  It shows people what you've tried, and it makes it easier to understand the problem and provide a solution.  You should show your segue code, so we can see what you're passing to the Settings view controller, the Settings code where you're trying to create a managed object, and the specific error(s) provided by Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to access your app delegate from another ViewController?

Just do like this:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
```

Comment: Yes, I already tried this into my second controller, but, Xcode is saying that AppDelegate is unknown

Comment: Mmm... But you can access it like that from the first controller just fine? That's definitely weird...